# Is one allowed to embarass idolaters and atheists in public?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, masecheth-avodah-zarah, embarrassment

From the story of Yehudah and Tamar, we know that it's better to die than embarass a fellow Jew in public. However, I've heard multiple times that Torah permits embarassing and insulting idolaters (and I assume atheists as well) in public? Is it true?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99331/16706